# Traveling with a 9-year old in the Red Sea Riviera, Hurghada, East Egypt area?

Tags: security, egypt

I am planning a 1-2 week trip to somewhere with sea and warmth. One contender is the Red Sea, probably somewhere along the [Red Sea Riviera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Sea_Riviera) (Hurghada etc). I've never been to an Arabic state, neither as tourist or otherwise. I (male) will be going alone with a 9-year old daughter. We'll mostly stay at one place and enjoy the beach, with infrequent outings to the close surroundings (i.e., no long day trips).

I'll figure the details out with my local travel agency, but would like to ask a general question: being from the EU, I feel pretty fine in places like Italy or Spain. I wouldn't expect being in danger booking a boat trip on Lake Garda, anytime. Yes, there is petty crime in any tourist location; but I believe with common sense most issues can be handled (stick around people; avoid small dark alleys in the night, look "normal" and don't flaunt around large € bills or expensive stuff, etc).

[This site](https://www.numbeo.com/crime/in/Hurghada-Egypt) shows "crime rising in Hurghada in the last 3 years: High", and neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_in_Egypt) nor [this article from 2017](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/welcoming-friendly-tourists-killed-egypt-10801009) paints a particularly rosy image, with terrorist attacks on tourist strands, security advisories by the UK government etc. On the other hand, random people keep telling me how nice it is around there.

Does that relate to your experience traveling over there? If I were to go alone or with another adult, I would be more relaxed about this, but frankly; as I'm alone with a child, I'll be having my hands full anyways, so having to look over my shoulder is not what I'm looking for.

TL;DR: did you, on your last visit to that area, feel pretty fine, or did you feel like you had to watch your back rather constantly? Where exactly did you go? If you felt safe (or insecure), for what reasons?

Comment: This will be closed as opinion-based, but if you want my opinion, I'd try Nuweiba in the Sinai. More isolated.

Comment: Check your country foreign office. Most of the countries gives some indications about travel (localized for own citizen, and expectation). This is always a source of good information (but on pessimistic side).  I was there some years ago, and it was also not so safe going in direction of desert, and I also got the news that now it is worse.

Answer (score 2):

You will be staying in a hotel with a huge beach, bars and a buffet. It is a fenced-out area so nobody undesirable will ever enter your field of vision (apart from occasional annoying vendors from hotel-approved plaza). It's like staying on cruise ship except it's not going anywhere.

You will probably be picked from the airport and transferred straight to hotel in their bus. Same with day-long tours. Your security is their concern. Unless you want to travel to a local city, which I don't advise against in general, but with a 9-year old you probably don't need it.